# Does adding environment variable affect app speed on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, environment-variables

So the question is pretty simple - does adding environmental variables affect application speed? In particular, I want to add `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` variable to a release commit, but I'm afraid it might affect app start speed. Any links or info on the topic would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual the answer is "it depends". In principle adding an environment variable to the environment of an app does not affect speed in a noticeable way.

However *if* you decide to set a *specific* variable there is a high probability that you *want* your application to interpret the contents of the variable in a specific way. This influence is entirely defined by the application and there is very little you can say "in general".

In your case `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` seems to only print "launch statistics", whatever that may be. Given it can be found on an Apple Webpage describing [iOS Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2239/_index.html) it does not appear to be wise to put it into a shipping build. The statistics would be "printed" (i.e. probably logged to some remote location) on your customer device. This may be useful during development where it might get printed to Xcode, but not on customer devices where you will never see the results.

*If* this should be a "magic" measure to make an application "run" in some better way I do not consider it a good solution and you should dig deeper to find the *actual* problem.

Comment: The variable is used to display pre-main start time in console and is not needed for app run in any way. While it does not affect speed in a **noticeable** way, from your answer I make a conclusion that it does affect speed in **some** way, that's why I believe it would be better to remove it. Thanks for the answer.